# Can we have some tag synonyms created?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-synonyms, reputation

According to [this](https://materials.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), we need 1250 reputation to create a tag synonym.

Due to the 200/day limit (which doesn't include accepted answers and bounties, but bounties can't be added yet for another 2 days), it will take some time for someone to reach 1250 reputation.

[This question](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/65/k-points-convergence-for-special-quasirandom-structures-sqs-of-the-same-materi) has created the tags: ***density-functional-theory***, which can be a synonym for the existing ***dft*** tag, and ***ab-initio-calculations*** which can be a synonym for the existing ***ab-initio*** tag.

- Perhaps we can wait a few more days (200 x 5 days = 1000 reputation, plus bounties and 
  association bonus, could get someone to 1250).
- Or we could have these synonyms created by CMs (although we don't want to be too much of a burden to them!)
- Or we could have this made possible at an earlier reputation level for Private Beta, due to the 200/day issue which makes it impossible to reach 1250 points right away (however I assume this idea has already come up in the past and hasn't yet been implemented, so I'm wouldn't really complain if this doesn't happen).

Comment: Related: [Can we not use 'dft' as a tag for density functional theory?](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25/49)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've merged and synonymized the two tags you mentioned, but in the opposite direction. I'm going to recommend non-shortened tags as much as possible. You have 35 characters; unless you can't fit it, use them.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks a tonne @Catija!

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think we should be creating tag synonyms right now. They will add to the pile of tags we will inevitably have to clean up before we leave private beta. I think we should try creating sensible tags and stick with them. Right now the load of questions is approachable and a manual retag should be fine. I personally would always opt for the more verbose versions, as they are generally more descriptive, especially in the absence of tag wikis. (And we don't yet have users who can approve them.) The issue with abbreviations was for example raised for DFT.