# What should the tag for "ab initio" be?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

- I had originally made the [ab-initio](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ab-initio) tag.
- Very soon afer, someone made the [ab-initio-calculations](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ab-initio-calculations) which (to me) seems redundant.
- I asked to have a tag synonym created so that [ab-initio-calculations](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ab-initio-calculations) maps to [ab-initio](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ab-initio): [Can we have some tag synonyms created?](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/can-we-have-some-tag-synonyms-created) The request was granted, but the other way around, basically because the former has the extra word compared to the latter.

I could understand why [dft](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dft) -> [density-functional-theory](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density-functional-theory) was the best choice, because it turns something from ambiguous to non-ambiguous. The point here though, is that **everyone using the dft tag is talking about density-functional-theory**. Claims have been made that "discrete Fourier transform" questions will come up, but I doubt it, and in the rare case when it does, the user may quickly see that "dft" was switched to "density-functional-theory" and if so, they certainly will change the tag to discrete-fourier-transform.

Regarding ab-initio, I was less keen on the synonym being created in the direction towards ab-initio-calculations rather than the other way around. I think "ab-initio" contains enough meaning, and I cannot foresee anyone mis-applying the tag. ab-initio-calculations is something even more specific though, and many question might have to do with ab-initio-methods in general.

In this question today: [Can DFT be considered an ab initio method?](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/518/5), the user was talking about the "concept" of ab-initio, not even the calculations or even methods, but just the concept.

As a follower of the ab-initio tag, I would have liked to see this question for sure. However the user didn't tag ab-initio because the available tag was ab-initio-calculations, which didn't quite *feel* right.

**To the followers of the ab-initio tag(s):** I wonder if there would be any objection to having an "ab-initio" tag, and having ab-initio-calculations, ab-initio-methods, ab-initio-concepts, ab-initio-theory, or anything anything else related to ab-initio, mapped as synonyms to the base tag ab-initio? If there is an objection, what is it about the ab-initio tag on its own, that is problematic from a practical standpoint?

Answer (score 2):

If with ab-initio(-calculations) you refer to wavefunction-based methods, then it would probably be better to call the tag like that.

Apparently in the physics community ([Is density functional theory an ab initio method?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33764/4945)) it is quite common to call DFT an ab-initio method, whereas other places it is a convention to mean wave-function based methods with ab-initio.

I've warned about generating synonyms prematurely, so consider this a second attempt.